# How to parallelize integrating in Mathematica 8

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods

Somebody have idea how to use all cores for calculating integration? I need to use parallelize or parallel table but how?

```
 f[r_] := Sum[(((-1)^n*(2*r - 2*n - 7)!!)/(2^n*n!*(r - 2*n - 1)!))*
 x^(r - 2*n - 1), {n, 0, r/2}]; 


 Nw := Transpose[Table[f[j], {i, 1}, {j, 5, 200, 1}]]; 

 X1 = Integrate[Nw . Transpose[Nw], {x, -1, 1}]; 

 Y1 = Integrate[D[Nw, {x, 2}] . Transpose[D[Nw, {x, 2}]], {x, -1, 1}]; 

 X1//MatrixForm
 Y1//MatrixForm
```

Comment: Also [on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/79218/954) and related question on [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/315337/45585).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one helps Integrate a bit by expanding the matrix elements first, 
things are doable with a little bit of effort.

On a quad-core laptop with Windows and Mathematica 8.0.4 the following code below runs 
for the asked DIM=200 in about 13 minutes,
for DIM=50 the code runs in 6 second.

---

```
$starttime = AbsoluteTime[]; Quiet[LaunchKernels[]]; 
DIM = 200; 
Print["$Version = ", $Version, "  |||  ", "Number of Kernels : ", Length[Kernels[]]]; 
f[r_] := f[r] = Sum[(((-1)^n*(-(2*n) + 2*r - 7)!!)*x^(-(2*n) + r - 1))/(2^n*n!*(-(2*n) + r - 1)!), {n, 0, r/2}]; 
Nw = Transpose[Table[f[j], {i, 1}, {j, 5, DIM, 1}]]; 
nw2 = Nw . Transpose[Nw]; 
Print["Seconds for expanding Nw.Transpose[Nm] ", Round[First[AbsoluteTiming[nw3 = ParallelMap[Expand, nw2]; ]]]]; 
Print["do the integral once: ", Integrate[x^n, {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> n > -1]]; 
Print["the integration can be written as a simple rule: ", intrule = (pol_Plus)?(PolynomialQ[#1, x] & ) :> 
     (Select[pol,  !FreeQ[#1, x] & ] /. x^(n_.) /; n > -1 :> ((-1)^n + 1)/(n + 1)) + 2*(pol /. x -> 0)]; 
Print["Seconds for integrating Nw.Transpose[Nw] : ", Round[First[AbsoluteTiming[X1 = ParallelTable[row /. intrule, {row, nw3}]; ]]]]; 
Print["expanding: ", Round[First[AbsoluteTiming[preY1 = ParallelMap[Expand, D[Nw, {x, 2}] . Transpose[D[Nw, {x, 2}]]]; ]]]]; 
Print["Seconds for integrating : ", Round[First[AbsoluteTiming[Y1 = ParallelTable[py /. intrule, {py, preY1}]; ]]]]; 
Print["X1 = ", (Shallow[#1, {4, 4}] & )[X1]]; 
Print["Y1 = ", (Shallow[#1, {4, 4}] & )[Y1]]; 
Print["seq Y1 : ", Simplify[FindSequenceFunction[Diagonal[Y1], n]]]; 
Print["seq X1 0 : ",Simplify[FindSequenceFunction[Diagonal[X1, 0], n]]]; 
Print["seq X1 2: ",Simplify[FindSequenceFunction[Diagonal[X1, 2], n]]]; 
Print["seq X1 4: ",Simplify[FindSequenceFunction[Diagonal[X1, 4], n]]]; 
Print["overall time needed in seconds: ", Round[AbsoluteTime[] - $starttime]];
```

Comment: Dear Mr Rolf how to transform this code if I need two integrals of  X1 = a*Integrate[Nw . Transpose[Nw], {x, -1, 0.3}]+b*Integrate[Nw . Transpose[Nw], {x, 0.3, 1}];  a and b constants. Thank you very much on this detail type. People should learn from you how to give the solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

I changed the integration of a list into a list of integrations so that I can use `ParallelTable`:

```
X1par=ParallelTable[Integrate[i, {x, -1, 1}], {i, Nw.Transpose[Nw]}];

X1par==X1

(* ===> True *)

Y1par = ParallelTable[Integrate[i,{x,-1,1}],{i,D[Nw,{x,2}].Transpose[D[Nw,{x,2}]]}]

Y1 == Y1par

(* ===> True *)
```

In my timings, with `{j, 5, 30, 1}` instead of `{j, 5, 200, 1}` to restrict the time used somewhat, this is about 3.4 times faster on my quod-core. But it can be done even faster with:

```
X2par = Parallelize[Integrate[#, {x, -1, 1}] & /@ (Nw.Transpose[Nw])]

X2par == X1par == X1

(* ===> True *)
```

This is about 6.8 times faster, a factor of 2.3 of which is due to `Parallelize`.

`Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` are not very trustworthy when parallel execution is concerned. I used `AbsoluteTime` before and after each line and took the difference.

---

**EDIT**

We shouldn't forget ParallelMap:

At the coarsest list level (1):

```
ParallelMap[Integrate[#, {x, -1, 1}] &, Nw.Transpose[Nw], {1}]
```

At the deepest list level (most fine-grained parallelization):

```
ParallelMap[Integrate[#, {x, -1, 1}] &, Nw.Transpose[Nw], {2}]
```

Comment: Is it possible to be faster using simplify form of formula
         f[r_] = FullSimplify[
         Sum[(((-1)^n*(2*r - 2*n - 7)!!)/(2^n*n!*(r - 2*n - 1)!))*
        x^(r - 2*n - 1), {n, 0, r/2}], r > 0 && r \[Element]  Integers]
simplifies to

$$
f(r)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (-1)^r 2^{r-3} x^{r-1} \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{1-r}{2},1-\frac{r}{2};\frac{7}{2}-r;\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\Gamma (r)}.
$$
But it doesn't work with this formula
     
 f[r_] := -(1/Gamma[r]) (-1)^r 2^(-3 + r) Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Xi]^(-1 + r)
    Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[(1 - r)/2, 1 - r/2, 7/2 - r, 
    1/\[Xi]^2];

Comment: @Sjoerd your 10K party is coming! Have you bought enough beer?

Comment: @George In the function mentioned in your comment Sqrt[[Pi]] should be Sqrt[Pi] and [Xi] should be \[Xi]. Also it speeds things up if you define Xi. In this case only the overhead of parallelization seems to overwhelm any gains brought by parallelization. Not sure why this is so

Comment: @belisarius I feel it's going to happen when I'm asleep, unfortunately, i.e., in a couple of minute. My significant other is calling (actually she is texting ;-)  )

Comment: @Sjoerd So I m going to drink my beer  alone :) Congrats in advance!

Comment: @mr.wizard Thanks for pushing me over the edge! Wow, I feel so different now.

Comment: I hope you like seeing all the deleted answers.  If not, take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110535/

Comment: @George I forgot about the StackOverflow comment's tendency to drop backslashes. Anyway, perhaps we should continue to look into the erratic performance of the parallelization tools. Perhaps you could post your last comment as a new question?